# The binding at system.serviceModel/bindings/wsHttpBinding does not have... error

Tags: c#, wcf

I am trying to include two endpoints in my WCF web based service - wsHttp and netTcp.
As shown in the `Web.config` below I have added them, but receive the following error when when I compile and click on Service.svc in my web browser:

**Error page:**

```
Server Error in '/MyService' Application. Configuration Error Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: The binding at system.serviceModel/bindings/wsHttpBinding does not have a configured binding named 'wsHttpBinding'. This is an invalid value for bindingConfiguration.

Source Error:

Line 16: </baseAddresses> Line 17:         </host>  Line 18:  <endpoint address="http://localhost:8090/Services/MyService" Line 19:                   binding="wsHttpBinding" Line 20:                 bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBinding"


Source File: C:\MyService\web.config    Line: 18

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1
```

**Web.config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add scheme="http" binding="wsHttpBinding"/>
    </protocolMapping>
    <services>
      <service
        name="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.MyService">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9001/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:8090/Services/MyService"
                  binding="wsHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBinding"
                  name="MyService_WsHttp"
                  contract="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.IService" />
        <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:9000/Services/MyService"
                  binding="netTcpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="tcpBinding"
                  name="MyService_Tcp"
                  contract="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.IService" />    
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

take this out:

```
          bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBinding"
```

from here:

```
address="http://localhost:8090/Services/MyService" 
                  binding="wsHttpBinding" 
                  bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBinding"
```

Comment: please mark as answer if its worked - reason for it is that if you're using 'out of the box' bindings (as you are...) then you've not made any configuration changes - which that attribute is meant to indicate.

Comment: When I use wsHttpBinding, it says contract must use DualHttpBinding ?!

Comment: @Hari are you developing a duplex service?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply . Yes Chris

Comment: you need to use wsDualHttpBinding (if I remember that right!) then. post up a Q and include your config.

Answer (score 1):

I don't thing that you have properly answer the question I'am sure he want to implement the 
a binding configuration so instead of removing `bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBinding`, just make sure that the binding in your and point match the one in your configure file.
Hope this will work

e.g:

```
<bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <!--Configure the Service operation instance object timeout of an endpoint -->
        <binding name="netTCP" receiveTimeout="00:00:10" />
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>

<endpoint address="PerSessionService" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="InstanceContext_PerSessionService.IPerSessionService" bindingConfiguration="netTCP">
```